# JS Convert A Function File To Allow Import and Use in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iife

Quite new to JS here. I have inherited an application where there is a JS file which I need to port so that I could import it to my VueJS application and utilize the functions available on it.

The JS file which I need to convert has the following method (redacted for brevity)

```
;(function(window) {
  'use strict';

  function extend( a, b ) {
    for( var key in b ) { 
        if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
            a[key] = b[key];
        }
    }
    return a;
  }

  function debunk(func, wait, immediate) {
    // ....Some code here..
  };

  var win = {width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight};

  function AccordionNavigation(el, options) {
    this.DOM = {};
    this.DOM.el = el;
    this.options = extend({}, this.options);
    extend(this.options, options);
    this._init();
  };

  AccordionNavigation.prototype.options = {
    layout: 'vertical',
    onOpenAccordion: function(a, b) { return false; }
    onCloseAccordion: function(a, b) { return false; }
  };

  AccordionNavigation.prototype._init = function() {
    this.DOM.accordions = [].slice.call(this.DOM.el.querySelectorAll('.accordionnav__item'));
    this.DOM.bars = [].slice.call(this.DOM.el.querySelectorAll('.accordionnav__bar'));

    this.totalAccordions = this.DOM.accordions.length;
    this.extraEl = document.querySelector(this.options.extramovable);

    this._initEvents();
  }

  AccordionNavigation.prototype._initEvents = function() {
    // Some code here...
  }

  window.AccordionNav = AccordionNav;
})(window);
```

So what I did is to rewrite part of the JS file, so that it could be exported and imported into my Vue application.

```
export default function (window){
  'use strict'
  // All the functions written above are here..
  window.TabsNav = TabsNav
}
```

And in my Vue component, I am importing it as:

```
<template>
  <!-- HTML Template Codes -->
</template>

<script>
  import AccordionNav from '@/externalJS/file.js'

  export default {
    name: 'MyComponent',
    data () {
      return {
        // Variables here...
        accnav: null
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      var a = this
      var options = { layout" 'vertical' }
      a.accnav = new AccordionNav(document.querySelector('acc.AccNav'), options)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Now, when I try to invoke any of the function coming from the imported AccordionNav JS file, it can't seem to find any of the method.

I put a console.log(AccordionNav) and it is returning the whole signature of the function, but it seems doing this line of code:

```
a.accnav = new AccordionNav(document.querySelector('acc.AccNav'), options)
```

The methods are not accessible to the a.accnav object.

Would love to know more about this and what I may be doing wrong.

Thanks.